# pairwise counting: SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table like this:

```
A | B
 ---
1 | 2 
2 | 1 
3 | 1 
1 | 3
1 | 3
5 | 6
```

I want to write a SQL query to count pairs such that (a,b) = (b,a).
In the above example since we have two pairs of (1,3) and one pair of (3,1), I want the corresponding count to be 3. Similarly the count for (1,2) and (2,1) would be 2.

The final result should look something like this:

```
A | B | count
 ---
1 | 2 | 2
1 | 3 | 3
5 | 6 | 1
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * from table join table where table.A = table.B and table.B = table.A
```

Once I get this, I thought I would do a count and group by. But this doesn't give me what I want.

Any leads appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select least(a, b), greatest(a, b), count(*)
from t
group by least(a, b), greatest(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do same thing with `CASE`

```
     SELECT 

  CASE WHEN a > b THEN b ELSE a end AS a, 
  CASE WHEN a < b THEN b ELSE a end AS b ,
  COUNT(*) CountValue
FROM Table1
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN a > b THEN b ELSE a end),
           CASE WHEN a < b THEN b ELSE a end
```